# How to test a Click event on Echarts using Jest/Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, echarts

I have a echarts-for-react bar graph. On barClick, the page redirects to a different url. How do I test for this click event using Enzyme/Jest?

```
const handleClick = (params) => {
  if(params.data){
    let url = get_route(params.value[2])
    window.open(url, "_self")
  }
  return null
};
```

```
let onEvents = {'click': handleClick};

<ReactEcharts
            option={this.getOption()}
            onEvents={onEvents}
            style={{width: '100%', height: `${height}px`}}
            className='react_for_echarts' 
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this `echarts` component, but generally to test it with enzyme you should:

1. Spy on your function to track its calls (you have to change it from an arrow function to a proper js function) `const spy = jest.spyOn(MyComponent.prototype, 'handleClick');`
2. Mount your component `const component = mount(<MyComponent/>);`
3. Simulate click on a desired button (?) `component.find(ReactEcharts).simulate('click');`
4. Update your component `component.update();`
5. Check if the function was called `expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();`